# I can't use LocaleStorage in NextJS

Tags: typescript, next.js

```
type productsTypeProps = {
  products: productsType[];
  cart?:string,
  wishlist?:string,
  fallbackValue?: any
};

const ProductsList: FC<productsTypeProps> = ({ products }) => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState<productsType[]>(
    typeof window !== undefined ?JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("wishlist") || "[]") : ''
  );
  const [wishlist, setWishlist] = useState<productsType[]>(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("wishlist") || "[]")
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
    localStorage.setItem("wishlist", JSON.stringify(wishlist));
  }, [cart, wishlist]);

  const addToCart = (product: productsType) => {
    setCart([...cart, product]);
  };

  const addToWishlist = (product: productsType) => {
    setWishlist([...wishlist, product]);
  };
```

I'm used typeof window but it still doesn't work. Please, help                   .............................................

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you use Next's SSR or SSG in some way, which causes (pre-)rendering of your page on the server, where `window` isn't defined as you mentioned.

The issue with

```
 const [cart, setCart] = useState<productsType[]>(
    typeof window !== undefined ?JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("wishlist") || "[]") : ''
  );
```

is that on the server, `cart` will be initialized as `''`, while on the client, during React Hydration, it will be initialized with the value parsed from `localStorage`, which will cause a content-mismatch error during hydration.

I assume you're getting the error:

> Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

### Solution

If your initial state value is in `localStorage`, you have initialize the state **inside a `useEffect` which only runs on the client**, like this:

```
 const [cart, setCart] = useState<productsType[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cart.length) return;
    
    const localVal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("wishlist") || "[]")

    if (Array.isArray(localVal) && localVal.length){
       setCart(localVal)   
    }

  }, []);
```

If you want to sync localStorage with your state, you can do something like this instead:

```
 const [cart, setCart] = useState<productsType[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cart.length){
       localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
       return;
    }

    const localVal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("wishlist") || "[]")

    if (Array.isArray(localVal) && localVal.length){
       setCart(localVal)   
    }

  }, [cart]);
```